# msg.d from asp.net webmethod is undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I'm trying to follow [this article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) to get a value from a webmethod using jQuery AJAX. I've cut it down to a one-input form.

Thing is, it always fails and msg.d is always undefined. In Firebug, I can see the POST and the data string  is formatted correctly. I cannot, for the life of me figure out why this keeps failing. The breakpoint set in my webmethod gets hit but the page displays a failure message before it's fully run.

Any ideas what's going on? Here's my code:

Basic form:

```
<div id="contact">
    <ul>
        <li><div>Name*</div>
        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtName" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName" />
        </li>               
        </ul>
        <ul class="submit">
            <li>* required</li>
            <li class="submit_button">

        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit" value="Submit"     id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit" />
            </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var name = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "Default.aspx/SendEmail",
                data: "{'name':'" + name.val() + "'}",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("success");
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("fail");
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SendEmail(string name)
{
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: what is the failure message?

Comment: @lante: The failure message in the alert is 'undefined'

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net 2.0 by any chance?

Comment: Just so you know, you can't `alert(msg.d)` in the error method because the first argument, which you've called msg is not the response like the `success` method, it's the jqXHR object which doesn't have a `d` property. That's why it's alerting undefined.

Answer (score -1):

You are returning a string from server , not JSON as AJAX `dataType` is looking for. String has no property `d`.

remove `dataType` option and try `alert(msg)`

Comment: I've removed the datatype parameter but alert(msg) now returns [object Object]

Comment: code shown is for string, alert suggests you are getting an object though...  use `console.log(msg)` and inspect data in browser console... what do you see there? Can also inspect the full request in console and see actual responseText

Comment: I have webmethods which return strings and they work just fine with JSON and Ajax..

Comment: OK.. you are getting alert from AJAX error, not success. `readyState=0` means you aren't connecting to server file

Comment: I'm definetely hitting the breakpoint set in the SendEmail method. I can also see that I'm passing name.val() into the name parameter in the same method. This should all work locally shouldn't it? This project is not live yet.

Comment: it should if path is right and no server code error. definitely not using `dataType:'json'`. Add 2 more arguments to `error( a,b.c)`...what does `c` show in console? It is the error text

Comment: ahhh  are you using jQuery 1.9? latest version? It has some AJAX changes in it

Comment: c shows '(an empty string)' in the console. I'm using jQuery 1.8.0.

Comment: did you look at b too? You should also look at full request in Net tab and look at all the headers, path, params sent, status etc. Clues are all in console

Comment: The headers seem fine - the data being sent is {'name':'brett'} but I still can't see anything obvious. I might resort to just having a traditional 'thank you' page.

Comment: is status 200? and URL appear correct? And does response show `"success"`?